# Microcontroller not working

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, st-link, j-link

I have designed and assembled a custom PCB that features the STM32F401RDT6 microcontroller. But unfortunately, I was unsuccessful in connecting to it via SWD to program it. I have tried the J-link EDU mini and the ST-LINK V3MINI debug probes but they were both unsuccessful at connecting to the target board. I have already replaced the microcontroller and oscillator once, so I don't think that the components are broken, but rather something I'm not seeing in the layout maybe.

**Schematic:**

[image]

What do you guys think may be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's the MCUs that are broken and they break as soon as you plug in the power supply.

The MCU core gets destroyed because VCAP is connected to 3.3V which is much more than the core can handle.

Also the crystal isn't used until your software or bootloader needs it for something, so the crystal cannot be the cause of not being able to connect via SWD.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when you are not reinventing the wheel, it's always recommended to compare existing solutions while designing electronics. Check this reference for your Microcontroller: https://stm32-base.org/boards/STM32F401CCU6-WeAct-Black-Pill-V1.2.html you will get the schematic here.

As rightly mentioned by a few people, you muct not connect VCAP pin to any voltage source. Try to cut the trace and see if your MCU recovers. If it's damaged, I'd recommend soldering a fresh MCU after altering the trace and then powering it up.

Next:

1. Check BOOT0 connection.
2. Preferably add a 10K PU resistor on your
   reset line.
3. UART0 is not exposed. All STM32 MCU's have inbuilt bootloader to perform DFU over UART0, USB, etc. UART0 is most efficient way to do this. You can try with USB as well.
4. XTAL does not matter for programming via. External programmer.

Comment: Pull-up on reset has not been recommended for about ten years, and before that, it was recommended only if there is a lot of EMI. And DFU only means uploading code via USB, not via other interfaces. USB is most efficient since it's fastest and already in the design. And certainly not all STM32 models have USB and etc bootloaders, some models only support UART. This model needs a working crystal for USB DFU to work, and the 16 MHz is definitely not the optimal crystal for that. So the board you link to is not a very good example how it should be done, it's actually very poor with many errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please have the Boot0 (pin 60) connected to GND.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: OK 
But as already mentioned by @Justme VCAP is not to powered by an external source, that could be error.